# Equation types in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

Given the following:

```
from sympy import var, Eq
var('I1 I2 I3 I4 I5')
```

Why does this work:

```
c_eq2=Eq(I1+I2-I4-I5,0)
```

But this gives an error?

```
>>> c_eq2=Eq(I1-I2=I4+I5)
File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

What are the restrictions in entering in an equation?

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but maybe you need to wrap the expression in quotes and make it a string?

Comment: Sympy expressions cannot use `=`, because Python doesn't let you overload `=`. Try `==`. Or, using `Eq`, try `Eq(I1 - I2, I4 + I5)`, because the `Eq` constructor takes two arguments.

Comment: @kaya3 ah, got it. Thanks for pointing this out. Yes `Eq(I1+I2,I4+I5)` works. Replacing the `=` with a`,` fixes it.